# Fluid disappears and appears during simulation on moving obstacle

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to make an animation with fluid and some moving character(obstacle). Fluid is shooting from a gun towards the character. Fluid is like honey. Fluid is landing on character's body. The character is moving so fluid should react on his moves. Here is the problem. Fluid doesn't keep character's body. Fluid disappears when character make step forward and appears when the character moves back. Also the amount of fluid's vertices is changing during simulation. When some part of fluid disappears amount of vertices disappears and opposite. How to make fluid stay on moving body? Why doesn't it stay on the body?
Maybe it is impossible to make this in blender. If it is true please give me some advice how to do this in other way. I need this animation to game which I make in unity.
Thanks.
There is my problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-IIcJxscbE&t=2s

There is a blend file
https://easyupload.io/p0agi7

Comment: I highly suspect, that the water glitches at the intersection between the half sphere and the rectangular shape. I tested a similar setup and the water stuck to the object just as I would expect it to.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: WhatAMesh you mean that the cause of this problem is the intersection between the half sphere and the rectangular shape? Didyou test fluid with for example only sphere without other shapes in object? Did you obtain good result with fluid simulation and moving object?